# angular-google-maps, access to regular google maps API

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I've been dabbling with the [angular implementation of the google maps API](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api)
and have been struggling to figure out how to access any of the regular API helpers.

My problem originally started as I wanted to center the map programmatic-ally, based on my markers. *This is proving to be quite weird, I seem to be missing either something small or I'm misunderstanding how to create a new map using this directive*

My understanding is that I need to access the google API via the `uiGmapIsReady` method:

```
  uiGmapIsReady.promise()
      .then(function(instances) {
        // simplified for one map
        return instances[0].map;
      })
      .then(function(map) {
        // here is have access to utility functions like like"map.getCenter()" via map
        console.log(map);
    });
```

The problem is, the above is a separate instance as opposed to my original map object I created and bound to the view. (If that makes sense)

EG. map has access to the helpers, but it isn't bound to the directive, and setting `$scope.map = map`, `_.merge($scope.map, map)`, or other variants isn't working (/ doesn't feel right, feels hacky)

**Controller code:**

```
    //Hide map until ready
    $scope.loadingIsDone = false;
    $scope.markers = [];     

    // map wont work without these "hard-coded" values
    $scope.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: 40,
        longitude: 13.37
      },
      zoom: 10
    };  

    uiGmapIsReady.promise()
      .then(function(instances) {
        return instances[0].map;
      })
      .then(function(map) {

         // id like to set the center and bounds based on markers
         // assuming it must happen here?

         uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(googleMaps) { 

            googleMaps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                var center =  map.getCenter();               
                googleMaps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(center); 
            }); 
        });
    });

    // get my data
    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {   

        someAPI.logIn.then(function(token) {        
            // supply token to get future request
            someAPI.getOffers(token).then(function(res) {  
                var markers = [];

                //convert data points to markers
                angular.forEach(res.data, function(value, key) {
                    markers.push(coordinate.MakeMarker(value));
                });

                // apply marker collection to scope object, and unhide map
                $scope.markers = markers;
                $scope.loadingIsDone = true;                  
            }); 
        });
    });
```

**View**

```
   <div ng-if="loadingIsDone" class="animate-if map-container">       
       <div id="map_canvas">
           <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" bounds="map.bounds"> 
              <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'"> </ui-gmap-markers> 
           </ui-gmap-google-map>
       </div>
  </div>
```

**Summary**

- How do I create a new map instance the correct way EG...
  `$scope.map =`
- ... to allow access to the normal (Google) API helpers via the bound object
- to allow me to set the Center and "bound" coo ordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to update your center, maybe you can use the code in the following jsfiddle, specifically the following:

```
this.addMarker = function(res) {
    if(this.marker) this.marker.setMap(null);
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        position: res.geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    this.map.setCenter(res.geometry.location);
}
```

[**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/MetalMonkey/1rLwxsuh/) this simply adds a marker and sets the marker's lat/long as its center. Hope this gives you some idea.